# Test laravel sanctum with tokens

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-sanctum

I would like to test if a user is logged out,I am using Sanctum with Laravel Breeze, I am trying like this:

```php
public function test_users_can_logout()
{
    $this->signIn();

    $response = $this->postJson(
        '/api/logout'
    );

    $this->assertGuest();
}
```

And this is `AuthenticatedSessionController .php`, This came from Breeze, I modified it:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{   
    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {                

        $request->authenticate();     
        
        $token = $request->user()->createToken('MyAuthApp')->plainTextToken;
        
        return response()->json(
            [
                'access_token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'user' => $request->user()
            ]
        );        
        
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {        
     
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();        
        return response()->json(
            [
                'message' => 'log out successfully'
            ]
        );
        
    }
}
```

LoginRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {                
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate the request's credentials.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->filled('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }

    /**
     * Ensure the login request is not rate limited.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function ensureIsNotRateLimited()
    {
        if (! RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 5)) {
            return;
        }

        event(new Lockout($this));

        $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.throttle', [
                'seconds' => $seconds,
                'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60),
            ]),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the rate limiting throttle key for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function throttleKey()
    {
        return Str::lower($this->input('email')).'|'.$this->ip();
    }
}
```

TestCase.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use App\Models\User;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;    

    protected function signIn($user = null)
    {        

        $user = $user ?: User::factory()->create();
        Sanctum::actingAs($user);        
        return $user;
    }
}
```

EDITED: now I am testing only the logout route, my test fails, maybe because sanctum is using cookies? is it ok use sanctum with breeze?

I would like to test if the token no longer exists, what can I do?

Comment: I am not right now in my home, so I cannot write code for you, but your first test is not right, you are testing 2 things, you are firstly login in the user and then login the user out, you have to only do 1 thing, in this case logout as you are testing that... so the first login part, just do something like the login controller is doing to create the token but in your test... second, to test your `destroy` (if the tokens already does not exist), just do the same as the test you are showing us, but remove the part where you login, so the user will create without tokens (hence, token not exist)

Comment: Question edited, now the test fails, it looks like because is it using cookies?